# split string, VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, numbers, text-files, split

I have a file txt file that holds 3 values each seperated by a space how can i assign each value to its own variable and use that for other things?

as example the numbers might be displayed in the text file as:

-1100.02 -1958.19 0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim line as String = "-1100.02 -1958.19 0.0"
Dim values() as Double = Array.ConvertAll(line.Split(New Char() { " "c }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmotyEntries), AddressOf Convert.ToDouble)
```

This will result in `values` being filled with numbers from the input string (assuming a set of  valid numbers on each line).

Answer (score 1):

In C#:

```cs
string s = File.ReadAllText(filename);
string[] nums = s.Split(' ');
```

So you can access nums[index] where index should be between 0 and 2.
Note that you MUST check if everything went ok...

If you need you can also try:

```cs
foreach (string num in nums)
{
    double d = double.Parse(num);
    // Here you can do what you want with d
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Translating Marco’s C# code to VB:

```
Dim s As String = File.ReadAllText(filename)
Dim nums As String() = s.Split(" "c)
```

To get numbers, you need to parse the strings separately. You can use Linq to do this:

```
Dim numbers As Double() = From num In nums Select Double.Parse(num)
```

Comment: to use you second part he should include LINQ, right? I'm not sure, but I think so.

Comment: @Marco The second part will work by default in the current VB.NET unless Linq has been explicitly disabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
dim strSplitted() as string = Line.split(" "c) 
' strSplitted(0), strSplitted(1) and strSplitted(2) will hold the values.
```

Line is the line in the file ofcourse :-)

**update:** code updated according to comments.

Comment: No need to separate the declaration from the initialisation. In fact, that’s highly discouraged. Also, don’t use `CChar(" ")`, VB offers a concise way to achieve this: just write `" "c`.

Comment: Ah, did not know that (although I was not so happy with the cchar...) Thanks, +1

Comment: okay but more to the point though how do i assign each to a variable

Comment: dim strValue as string = strSplitted(0) ? But strSplitted is already a variable. @Konrad, I'm not sure if that's discouraged, I prefer declarations to be at the top of the function/class to improve the readability. But the compiler will optimize the code at the end.

Comment: “I'm not sure if that's discouraged” – essentially all style guides agree on this: a declaration should be as close as possible to the first usage, **not** at the top of the method. That’s an anachronism from old BASIC versions and C, where the declarations *had* to be at the top. It contradicts the design principle of keeping variable scope as small as possible, and the single responsibility principle (since it makes variables prone to reuse).